# Can you write unescaped search terms in the Vim command line?

Tags: vim

When I do a search and replace on a yanked line that has characters that require escaping it's really annoying to have to go back through the command line string and escape all the special characters.

Is there a way to use a literal (raw) string modifer like in python: `str = r'\unescaped\'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\V` modifier:

```
:%s/\V$foo//g
```

See also [`:help /magic`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic)

Comment: It appears the literal backslash always needs to be escaped i.e. \\. Sigh.

Comment: True, I thought of another solution... Using a different character than \ for the search and replace separaters, e.g. :%s;\foo\;bar;

Answer (score 0):

I just thought of doing this instead: `:%s;\foo\;bar;g`. This solves the escape the backslash problem Manni points out.